# Python ignoring while loop with True condition

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

I'm writing a menu for a simple game, so I thought to use a while loop to let the user choose his wanted option by clicking on it. While my program works properly until this loop, it does not continue when reaching the line of the following loop:

```
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)        # This is the last line processed.
while True:                           # This line ist not processed.
    (curx,cury)= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(cursor,(curx-17,cury-21))
    pygame.display.flip()
    # rating values of the cursor position and pressed mouse button below:
    (b1,b2,b3) = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()    #getting states of mouse buttons
    if (b1 == True or b2 == True or b3 == True): # "if one mouse button is pressed"
        (cx,cy) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if (px <= curx <= px+spx and py <= cury <= py+spy):
            return (screen,0)
        elif (ox <= curx <= ox+sox and oy <= cury <= oy+soy):
            return (screen,1)
        elif (cx <= curx <= cx+scx and cy <= cury <= cy+scy):
            return (screen,2)
        else:
            return (screen,3)
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

I have already checked such things like wrong indentation.

BTW my interpreter (python.exe, Python 2.7.11) always does not respond after reaching this line of the

```
while True:
```

Because the question was asked in a deleted answer:

I had a print("") between every above shown line to find the problematic line.
As I wrote 4 lines above: The interpreter (and with it the debugger and bug report) has crashed without any further response.

The whole code of this function is:
    # MAIN MENU
def smenu (screen,res,menuimg,cursor):
    #preset:
    x,y = res
    click = False

```
print("preset") # TEST PART

# Fontimports, needed because of non-standard font in use
menu = pygame.image.load("menu.png")
playGame = pygame.image.load("play.png")
options = pygame.image.load("options.png")
crdts = pygame.image.load("credits.png")

print("Fontimport") # TEST PART


#SIZETRANSFORMATIONS
# setting of sizes
smx,smy = int((y/7)*2.889),int(y/7)
spx,spy = int((y/11)*6.5),int(y/11)
sox,soy = int((y/11)*5.056),int(y/11)
scx,scy = int((y/11)*5.056),int(y/11)

print("setting of sizes") # TEST PART

# setting real size of text 'n' stuff

menu = pygame.transform.scale(menu,(smx,smy))
playGame = pygame.transform.scale(playGame,(spx,spy))
options = pygame.transform.scale(options, (sox,soy))
crdts = pygame.transform.scale(crdts, (scx,scy))
cursor = pygame.transform.scale(cursor,(41,33))

print("actual size transformation") # TEST PART 

#DISPLAY OF MENU
# fixing positions
mx, my = int((x/2)-((y/7)/2)*2.889),10 # position: 1. centered (x) 2. moved to the left for half of the text's length 3. positioned to the top(y), 10 pixels from edge
px, py = int((x/2)-((y/11)/2)*6.5),int(y/7+10+y/10) # position: x like above, y: upper edge -"menu"'s height, -10, - height/10
ox, oy = int((x/2)-((y/11)/2)*5.056),int(y/7+10+2*y/10+y/11)
cx, cy = int((x/2)-((y/11)/2)*5.056),int(y/7+10+3*y/10+2*y/11)

print("fixing positions") # TEST PART

# set to display
#screen.fill(0,0,0)
screen.blit(menuimg,(0,0))
screen.blit(menu,(mx,my)) 
screen.blit(playGame,(px,py)) 
screen.blit(options,(ox,oy))
screen.blit(crdts,(cx,cy))
pygame.display.flip()

print("set to display") # TEST PART

# request for input (choice of menu options)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
print("mouse visible")  # TEST PART last processed line
while (True):
    print("While-loop") # TEST PART
    curx,cury = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(cursor,(curx-17,cury-21))
    pygame.display.flip()
    # decision value below
    (b1,b2,b3) = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() # getting mouse button's state
    if (b1 == True or b2 == True or b3 == True): # condition true if a buton is pressed
        (cx,cy) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if (px <= curx <= px+spx and py <= cury <= py+spy):
            return (screen,0)
        elif (ox <= curx <= ox+sox and oy <= cury <= oy+soy):
            return (screen,1)
        elif (cx <= curx <= cx+scx and cy <= cury <= cy+scy):
            return (screen,2)
        else:
            return (screen,3)
    time.sleep(0.05)
print("directly skipped")
```

Comment: have you tried removing the parenthesis at `(curx,cury)` ?

Comment: Yes, I did: It has changed nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would comment but can't because of low rep.

The problem might be, that you're returning a value to a while loop outside a function.

Although it's a bit weird that your interpreter/IDE isn't giving you the correct Error message for it.

Comment: While I think it's weird that python tries to return values from a while-loop inside a function than to return values of the function, it's hard to believe that it's a fatal error to the official interpreter of the python foundation that just ends up with a crashing interpreter. It has no protection to such a mistake it can't handle.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the following line of your code:

```
if (b1 == True or b2 == True or b3 == True):
```

This condition never becomes true so you are stuck into the while loop without  your function returning anything.

Comment: The idea of this program was the following: It should remain in the loop until you press a mouse button on one of three specific fields to choose an option. Thing is, it doesn't even start to process the loop. The condition will become true if you press a mouse button, according to the documentation on pygame.org .